# MP4Box comparing to Qt-faststart

Tags: video, file, transcoding

Since I have no idea about qt-faststart (and a little with MP4Box) are there any online resources about them(haven't found much)? Which is better? What about their differences?
Especially if i want to create hinted video files for android devices, which one is the best?

Answer (score 5):

One is a single purpose tool, one is a virtual tool chest of gadgets.

- **qt-faststart**: Single purpose: Move the MOOV atom.  That's it, nothing else.  Small (13kb executable on OSX) easy to compile.
- **MP4Box**: Larger (~2500 KB) and capable of oh-so-much-more.  From the [documentation](http://gpac.wp.institut-telecom.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation/):

> MP4Box is a multimedia packager, with
>   a vast number of functionalities:
>   conversion, splitting, hinting,
>   dumping and others

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous:

- "hinted video files" refer to the notion of "hint tracks" used by streaming servers (such as Apple's old Darwin Streaming Servers) to form RTP packets from media tracks (audio, video ...). There is nothing specific to Android here. Anyway, MP4Box can be used for producing the hint tracks, using commands like:

  ```
  MP4Box -hint file.mp4
  ```
- What qt-faststart does is reorder the boxes in the file to help progressive download and playback of the file. It is not at all related to hinting. MP4Box can also be used to change the order of the boxes and to control the interleaving of the payload of the different tracks (audio, video, subtitles ...) using:

  ```
  MP4Box -inter 500 file.mp4
  ```

for an interleaving window of 500 ms.